# Error "Connection to host closed" while using pseudo terminal

Tags: shell

I am trying to run the below command. But it is giving me an error that connection is closed.

```
ssh host -l user -t "nohup sh path_of_the_sh_file &"
```

If I only run

```
ssh host -l user -t..
```

it is working but if I want to run a script its not working.

Comment: Is there any reason you are using the `-t` option? Try to skip it. Do you get any response from the command, is there a `nohup.out` file on the remote system?